# Java Mongodb Aggregate Projection Computed

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a field in the following format :

```
loc : { geo: {coor: []}}
```

I am unable to fetch this field using java com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.aggregate, Aggregates.project(
                                  Projections.fields( Projections.computed()))
method.

Comment: Could you please complete the question with why do want to or what would you like to achieve?

Comment: @mgyongyosi I want to fetch the "coor" field which is inside the "loc" field, but I am unable to fetch it using the aggregate project method

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Projections.computed("coor", "$loc.geo.coor")`